# Let f(x) be a non constant thrice differentiable function such $f(x)=f(6-x)$ and $f’(0) =0 = f’(2)=f’(5)$. Find minimum number of roots

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, roots

> Let f(x) be a non constant thrice differentiable function such $f(x)=f(6-x)$ and $f’(0) =0 = f’(2)=f’(5)$. Find minimum number of roots of $(f’’(x))^2 +f’(x)f’’’(x)=0$ in the interval $x\in [0,6]$

Clearly $f’(x)=-f’(6-x)$

So $f’(1)=f’(5)=f’(4) = f’(2) = f’(6)=f’(0)=0$

Also $f’(3) =0$

This all I was able to find out. How should I proceed after this?

Comment: Possibly useful $(f''(x)) ^2+f'(x)f'''(x)=(f''(x) f'(x)) '$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the fact that $(f’’(x))^2 +f’(x)f’’’(x)=\dfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm dx}(f'(x)f''(x))$.

Since, you have found out that $f'(x)$ has atleast $7$ roots, it implies $f''(x)$ will have atleast $6$ roots, thus $f'(x)f''(x)$ will atleast have $13$ roots and thus it's derivative will atleast have $12$ roots.

Comment: Incidentally, all these roots are indeed in the $[0,6]$ interval, but that's probably an easy argument for the OP to make.

Comment: @Aditya Why should $f(x)$ be a polynomial? $f''(x)$ has **atleast** (note that not "exactly") $6$ roots because $f'(x)$ had atleast $7$ roots. This you can see by drawing the graph of a function, the number of hills and valleys you can count are the roots of derivative of $f(x)$, so if a function has $n$ roots, that is, it cuts the $x$ axis $n$ times, it's slope would have become $0$ atleast $n-1$ times.

Comment: @Aditya first you explain me why do you think it should be a polynomial, you can try giving me a counter example of product of 2 functions which are not polynomials and whose roots are not equal to the sum of roots of individual functions.

Comment: Never mind I got it, thanks for the help

Comment: Had it be $x\in [0,3]$, what would the changes be?

Comment: In that case, of course consider only the roots $0,1,2,3$. Then $f''(x)$ will have atleast $3$ roots, so product of them will atleast have $7$ roots, and it's derivative will atleast have $6$ roots.

Comment: Isn't there a possibility that $f'(x)$ and $f''(x)$ have common roots? In that case, $f'(x)f''(x) $ will have less than 13 roots.

Comment: @AnkitSaha No. It isn't possible, can you think why? Hint is already given in one of my comments above.

Comment: Got it. But it's wrong to say that isn't possible. It is certainly possible. But then I realized that we are only dealing with the minimum number of roots possible. That case gives more than the minimum number of roots possible, so we aren't interested in that.

Comment: @AnkitSaha Yes, you are correct. I didn't pay attention in my last comment, but it is reflected in my answer already :)